# include files in cl makefile

Tags: makefile, include, include-path, cl

I'm questioning the structure of a cl makefile.

I have the changes in place discarding gcc replacing with cl.

How do I tell the compiler where the include files are for the .C files that it is compiling?   Does the same -I tag work that is used in a gnu type makefile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/I` to specify the path to include folder.

Comment: where? After the compile option? Didn't work in my mak file from openSSL. The INC= option didnt work either

Comment: @BrianReinhold, add a minimal working example, so we can help you.